# select all results from only certain tables Using SQL in C# from a stored procedure that returns multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that returns about 20 tables.

i.e.:

```
TABLE 1
    id|a
    01|whatever
TABLE2   
    id|b
    01|whatever
TABLE3  
    id|c
    01|whatever
    02|whatever2
    03|whatever3
    04|whatever4
```

I use the following code to only grab the result from the tables with only 1 column and 1 row:

```
            sqlReader.Read();
            rows = Convert.ToString(sqlReader.GetValue(0));
            sqlReader.NextResult();
```

When I move to the next result, what can I use to get the results of the tables (would be helpful to grab only columns with no NULL values as well)?

EDIT:

How do I get from the TABLE with COLUMN 'c'

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. showing input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: no input needed...will show some example tables

Comment: rows = Convert.ToString(sqlReader.GetValue(1));